# Unconfirmed Transaction - Paid Fees

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

wondering if anyone can help me.  I moved funds from one wallet to another with transaction 582386d5b5480804535cf382727ab72b9a09dd1435b3444f18c20617d3198a65.  Fees were dutifully paid by my wallet.  I've never had a transaction take more than an hour or two to confirm if fees are paid.  Says it spent unconfirmed inputs?  Anyone know what it is, and how to get my money back if it does not confirm?

Thanks much!

Comment: blockchain.info now says "Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is due to the "malleability attack" that was going on; it can be that the transaction has gone through with a different transaction ID.  It would be easier if you disclose the input and/or output address.